# Django: More pythonic __unicode__

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, string-formatting

All my django-models have **unicode** functions, at the moment these tend to be written like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Unit: %s  -- %s * %f' % (self.name, self.base.name, self.mul)
```

However, Code Like a Pythonista, at http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#string-formatting points out that `self.__dict__` is a dictionary, and as such the above can be simplified to:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Unit: %(name)s -- %(base.name)s * %(mul)f' % self.__dict__
```

This works, except for the "base.name", because python tries to look up `self.__dict__['base.name']` which fails, while self.base.name works.

Is there an elegant way of making this work, even when you need to follow foreign-key-relationships ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%` string formatting doesn't support attribute access, but [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (since 2.6) does:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'Unit: {name:s} -- {base.name:s} * {mul:f}'.format(**self.__dict__)
```

Comment: Excellent ! Why these dual methods of string-formatting ? Are there some situations where .format() should not be used, or should I just change to always use this for consistency ?

Comment: @Agrajag `format` was added in 2.6, so the only reason to use `%` formatting is if you're writing code for old systems or if you want to make your code look like C.